# How to make a module to make imports to other files

Tags: python, module

I have a structure below,

```
utils
   __init__.py
   utils.py
models
  __init__.py
  classifier.py
webapp
  __init__.py
  run.py
```

Suppose I have a function named `tokenize` in utils.py, I can import this function in run.py file like that `from utils.utils import tokenize` but when I try to import this in classifier.py file, I get the error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have this difference (run.py success and classifier.py fail), unless you rely on some framework.

If you define project as above without any framework, you will meet "No module named utils.utils" also in run.py, because you don't import related path in sys.path.

but if you use some framework, you need to check related framework code to find difference.